# Web "frameworks" for Haxe to deploy in a PHP environment?

Tags: php, web-frameworks, haxe

Lately I've been taking a look at [Haxe](http://haxe.org), to build an application to be deployed to Apache running PHP. Well, while it looks like it might suit my needs (deploying to PHP, but not using an awful language), I haven't found anything to make the actual application development easier than building a traditional non-MVC PHP app. Are there any toolkits/frameworks that I'm missing, that would be worthwhile?

It'd be nice if it were MVC inspired, and I'd definitely want an easy way to use nice URLS, though I could settle for mod_rewrite rules if necessary.

Edit: The idea is to **not** use something like CakePHP on the PHP end, but to instead use something like CakePHP on the Haxe end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a port of PureMVC for Haxe: https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-haxe-standard-framework/wiki

As far as I know this the only thing for Haxe, but there are discussions on the mailing list about creating a own framework, but this could take a while.

Comment: The home page looks like it has been abandoned.

Comment: @Anwar probably because a lot of things have changed in the 13 years since this answer was made.

Answer (score 4):

I'm happy to say that haXigniter has been completely rewritten, to get away from the PHP-framework-style as mentioned by Marek. Now it adheres much more to better OO-principles and is also a standard haXe library, so upgrades are much simpler. Please check it out at http://github.com/ciscoheat/haxigniter.

Comment: Haxigniter is an outdated project nowadays, ufront is recommended instead: https://github.com/ufront/ufront

Answer (score 3):

I see that someone is starting to develop an MVC framework for Haxe called "Hails", though I don´t know if it is usable yet.

hails: A minimal Rails-inspired MVC web-framework for Haxe / PHP

http://code.google.com/p/hails/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at HaXigniter, a new kid on the block:

http://github.com/ciscoheat/haxigniter

Answer (score 1):

I would recon you to do your own.
The problem with frameworks above (Excluding PureMVC) is that they were designed for particular language.
Haxigniter is a good copy, but it has the architecture that was kind of enforced by PHP4.

Its a good excersise!
Let's you understand the differences and work out bottomline mechanics - and this is very important as your haxe code will be translated ( so you have double abstraction 1. translation 2. framework its good to know how to work thing out ;])

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a Haxe-based toolkit/framework for NekoVM/PHP. It is also built around a Zend Framework/Ruby-on-Rails-ish MVC workflow and has various classes for authentication, caching, form validation, session management etc. It can be compiled to both NekoVM and PHP and I have already used this library for a couple of websites. Unfortunately there is not much documentation available right now but I am working on that for the upcoming version 1 release of the library.

The project is hosted at http://code.google.com/p/toolkat

Answer (score 1):

There is also ufront:

- http://lib.haxe.org/p/ufront
- http://code.google.com/p/ufront/

It works with php and neko.

Answer (score 0):

See
 [forum FAQ ( 7th entry )](http://haxe.org/forum/thread/1323), but the list and links may not be still relevant, so below is a revised list of some that seem current.

- [poko](http://code.google.com/p/poko/)
- [hxquery](http://haquery.com/haquery/)
- [uform](http://haxe.org/com/libs/ufront)
- [hxWiki](https://github.com/ncannasse/hxWiki)

But if you are interested in just MVC structures then I suspect more robot legs type approaches maybe better, and injection is also useful.

- [unject](https://github.com/ciscoheat/unject/wiki/Description-and-Quickstart)
- [cube](https://github.com/xirsys/cube)
- [inject](https://github.com/massiveinteractive/minject)
- [robotlegs](https://github.com/massiveinteractive/mmvc)